# How can I delete values from input fields after submitting

Tags: php, html, mysql

How exactly is `IF EXIST` function used in MySQL?
    Alternatively, how can one make sure that the values previously filled into the input fields are cleared completely so that they are not re-posted once the page is reloaded?

This is a slice of my code

```
<?php
function testInput($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    $user = testInput($_POST['userName']);
    $fName = testInput($_POST['fName']);
    $lName = testInput($_POST['lName']);
    $fPass = md5(testInput($_POST['fPass']));
    $rPass = md5(testInput($_POST['rPass']));
    $gender = testInput($_POST['gender']);
}               
?>
```

I want to make sure that the value of my variables='' every time I refresh my page.

Comment: Make a `header('Location: ...');` redirect to the same page.

Comment: You set the form values in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is to prevent repost or backbutton repost

there are many ways to do this

- use of session cookie and only allow that session to post once in php
- using ajax to post to self or a new page in php so refreshing or backing will prevent repost
- iframe the form will also do the trick
- Post + Redirect to self

Comment: exactly, I am trying to prevent the repost...I would go with the first option as I am somewhat unfamiliar with the other options...Thank you. W

Comment: @user3386046 Most common approach are use of ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ or just redirect to same page (which will clear the `post` data)